# set background-image without set height

Tags: css

how to set image background without set height ?

```
#Header {
    background: #eee url("../Images/Banner.gif") repeat-x;
 }

<div id="Header">

</div>
```

But the image is not displayed.However, the the following code picture will be displayed.

```
    #Header {
        background: #eee url("../Images/Banner.gif") repeat-x;
height=150px;
     }
```

Why do I need to adjust the height?How to measure height automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is the *background* of the div. If the div has no content or set dimensions, and is not able to be seen, how will you be able to see its background? The answer is to put some content into the div. If you are only trying to show this image within the div, then instead of making it the background, put the image as actual html content within the div.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with the css3 property background-size and use it like:

```
background-size: auto
```